# When you change a job, do you leave your current job first and then go to interviews, or vice versa?

Tags: interviewing, job-change, employment

Assume a small-company leaving scenario.

-Do you leave any forward notification before leaving? (a week, a month?)

-Do you continue working until month's end, or just leave whenever? In the case of the latter, how much do you get paid for your last month?

-When you get a new job, do you begin immediately, from next Monday or from next month?

Comment: Your contract should tell you how much notice you're required to give. You're likely to get paid for exactly the amount of hours you officially worked during your last month, logically You begin whenever you agreed that you'd begin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When you change a job, do you leave your current job first and then go
>   to interviews, or vice versa?

It's far better to search for your next job while you are currently working. It removes the financial pressure and urgency that might steer you to take a less than optimal position. And many interviewers look more favorably on a candidate who is working than one who isn't.

The steps I suggest:

- Locate new jobs
- Interview with several
- Get an offer from at least one
- Negotiate the terms of the offer you prefer
- Accept the offer that most meets your needs
- Negotiate a start date with your future employer (take into account the notice period plus any additional non-paid time off you want)
- Sign the offer sheet/contract which includes all details of employment
- Give your notice at your current company
- Determine the notice period in conjunction with your current employer (2 weeks in the US is traditional. Some contracts require more. Other locales have other traditional/legal requirements)
- Work in as professional manner as possible until the end of your notice period
- Take time off if you have planned that within your start date
- Start your new job on your start date
- Live long and prosper

Comment: In general, +1, but don't you need to determine your notice period for the current job before agreeing a start date with the new employer?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend having a new job lined up before you quit your old (or announce your plans to). just in case something unexpected stalls in-between, you don't want to be in limbo with less financial options